# if/else trouble onPostExecute on a RegisterActivity

Tags: java, android

I am just new in programming world with no experience. I am about to finish my Android project but my problem is: My toast message always says Success even if I entered the exists phone no from my application. Please help me with the correct code!! (i am doing this for a long time) and the query is executed right function but the message is not shown properly.

```
//java
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public SignupActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String fullName = arg0[0];
      //  String userName = arg0[1];
        String passWord = arg0[1];
        String phoneNumber = arg0[2];
        String emailAddress = arg0[3];

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
        //    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
            data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
            data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

        link = "http://mangoair.in/MangoAir_User/mangoair_reg/tryrr.php" + data;

            //   link = "http://hostogen.com/mangoair10/tryrr.php" + data;

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

String jsonStr = result;

 if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                 else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               // Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON Please data Fill all the records.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // Toast.makeText(context, "Please LogIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Try to print query_result and check your if/else according to it.

Comment: can you post response .so that we can check

Comment: you need to put this line `return result;` outside of your `try-catch` block in your `doInBackground` method.

Comment: i am puting return result outside of try-catch block but t shows same message again "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfully"

Comment: when user already exist in database

Comment: Check what the actual response contains. If it indeed contains "SUCCESS" you need to figure out why. Your code seems fine to me though.

Comment: i have only the problem with if else statement the statement are not work proper my data is inserted and shows message SUCCESS but when record is exist then it also shows SUCCESS message instead of FAILURE i want to display FAILURE message when record is exist and query is properly run with database doing proper operations.